# How to write a move-method in the Node.js module, which exports a Game-class for a Tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, node-modules

I'm writing a Tic-tac-toe game, which allows playing a game between 2 users in different browsers, using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript (ES6), Node.js with express und socket.io modules.

For the game logic, I need to create a new module, that exports Game-class and describes the game state as well as the moves. A move-method within this class should use 2 arguments - symbol("X" or "O") and field(0 to 8), so basically who clicked and where.

By relevant move, the Move-method should change a game state and return an empty string.

By irrelevant move, a game state shouldn't change instead an error string should be returned.
The following irrelevant moves should be recognized:
1. Move after the game is over;
2. It is not a Symbol's turn;
3. The field is not free;

I also have the following test program, to make sure everything is set up correctly:

```
"use strict";

const gameModule = require('./GameModule.js');

const expect = (test, res1, res2) => {
  if (res1 !== res2) {
    console.log('Error in Test ' + test);
    console.log('received: "' + res1 + '"');
    console.log('expected: "' + res2 + '"');
    process.exit(1);
  } 
};

const game1 = new gameModule.Game('X');
expect( 1, game1.move('X', 0), '');
expect( 2, game1.move('X', 0), 'Irrelevant move: It is not X turn!');
expect( 3, game1.move('O', 2), '');
expect( 4, game1.move('X', 2), 'Irrelevant move: Field 2 is not free!');
expect( 5, game1.move('X', 4), '');
expect( 6, game1.move('O', 8), '');
expect( 7, game1.move('X', 3), '');
expect( 8, game1.move('O', 5), '');
expect( 9, game1.move('X', 6), 'Irrelevant move: The game is over!');
expect(10, game1.result, 'O'); // O wins

const game2 = new gameModule.Game('O');
expect(11, game2.move('O', 0), '');
expect(12, game2.move('X', 1), '');
expect(13, game2.move('O', 2), '');
expect(14, game2.move('X', 4), '');
expect(15, game2.move('O', 7), '');
expect(16, game2.move('X', 3), '');
expect(17, game2.move('O', 5), '');
expect(18, game2.move('X', 8), '');
expect(19, game2.move('O', 6), '');
expect(20, game2.result, '-'); // no decision

const game3 = new gameModule.Game();
expect(21, game3.currentPlayer.length, 1); // Random Starting player

console.log("Test OK");
```

It should be also mentioned, that game uses an Array of 9 empty strings as a game field, which corresponds to the values a server gets when a client clicks one of the fields, and a first player("X" or "O") is randomly assigned at a begin of a game.

Here is what I already have for a Game-class, but I cannot figure out how do I switch a player after a relevant move is done, considering that the game starts with a different player each time.

````
"use strict";

 class Game {

   constructor(el = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "X" : "O" ) {
     this.currentPlayer = el;
     this.gameField = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
     this.result = "";
   }

   move(symbol, field) {

     this.currentPlayer = symbol;

     if (!this.currentPlayer) {
       return `Irrelevant move: It is not ${symbol} turn!`;
     };

     if (this.gameField.every(field => field !== "")) {
       return `Irrelevant move: The game is over!`;
     };

     if (this.gameField[field] !== "") {
      return `Irrelevant move: Field ${field} is not free!`;
     };

     this.gameField.splice(field, 1, symbol);

     symbol = "X" ? this.currentPlayer = "O" : this.currentPlayer = "X";

     return "";
   }
 }

 exports.Game = Game;
 ```
````

Comment: Describe the issue with `move`, have you debugged it? Write which tests fail or make a runnable demo on codesandbox or stackblitz or something similar.

Comment: @barbsan test program returns the following mistake: Error in Test 1
received: "Irrelevant move: Field 0 is not free!"
expected: ""  even though the gameFiled array is empty..

Comment: You set the "X" on 0 and then check whether the 0 field is free... Rethink the order of operations according to your tests, next one test forces you to check turn before telling whether the field is empty, I don't even look at the rest

Comment: @barbsan thank you, I've changed the order and the first test went ok, but I cannot figure out how to switch to the next player after a relevant move is done. I've changed the code in the question

Comment: Well, once you set O or X, you should change `currentPlayer` (hint: you have unused `nextPlayer` variable)

Comment: @barbsan I understand that, but it seems I cannot find a right spot or I change it wrong. In the second test I need to get a "Not your turn" message but it returns a "field is not free" message instead, even though I check for a relevant turn first in a method. I've updated the code in the question. If you could advise what have I done wrong, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Your code was better before. You just had to add line `this.currentPlayer = nextPlayer;` after `this.gameField.splice(field, 1, symbol);`

Comment: I don't get these introduced changes: 1. `symbol = "X" ? ` is not a check, it's assignment; 2. `!this.currentPlayer` checks whether `this.currentPlayer` is not assigned, you'll get the same result for "X" and "O". If you don't get the code add some `console.log(someVariableYouWantSee)` and see in console what it contains

Comment: @barbsan I understood my mistakes, thanks. I've returned it to the previous state and it functions now.